# Run multiple JUnit tests with Ant

Tags: java, ant, junit, ant-junit

probably this is a very basic question but I am new to java, so please bear with me.
I am trying to run java task in ant and I want to know if there is any way to get all the name of the classes inside a folder in ant?

This is the build.xml file

```
<project default='run-test'  basedir=".">
  <property name="src" value="src"/>
  <property name="test" value="test"/>
  <property name="build" value="build"/>
  <property name="build-classes" value="build/classes"/>
  <property name="build-test-classes" value="build/test/classes"/>
  <property name="junit4" value="/usr/share/java/junit4.jar"/>

  <target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="${build-classes}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${build-test-classes}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="compile" depends="init">
    <javac includeantruntime="false" 
       srcdir="${src}" 
       destdir="${build-classes}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="compile-test" depends="compile">
    <javac includeantruntime="false" 
       classpath="${junit4}:${build-classes}"
       srcdir="${test}" 
       destdir="${build-test-classes}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="run-test" depends="compile-test">
    <java classpath="${junit4}:${build-classes}:${build-test-classes}"
      classname="org.junit.runner.JUnitCore"
      args="myclass.MyClassTest"/> <---This is my problem
  </target>

  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build}"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

I have to manually mention the name of the class in the arguments.
Is there any way where I can only mention the folder and all the class names will be taken up as arguments for the javatask  automatically?

Comment: I can't think of a way.  You're best option is to probably write a custom Ant task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ant ships with a task for [running JUnit tests](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html).

In the `run-test` target in your example, replace the `<java>` task with the following:

```
<junit>
  <formatter type="plain" usefile="false"/>
  <classpath>
    <pathelement location="${junit4}"/>
    <pathelement location="${build-classes}"/>
    <pathelement location="${build-test-classes}"/>
  </classpath>
  <batchtest>
    <fileset dir="${build-test-classes}">
      <include name="**/*.class"/>
    </fileset>
  </batchtest>
</junit>
```

Comment: can this be done without using the JUnit task of ant?

Comment: It can be done by duplicating what the `<junit>` task already does. The Apache Ant source code will show what the task does.

Comment: Also on a second thought can I put a file set that will refer to all the java test class files in the args of the run-test task?